# C# - List to hold multiple object types inherited from the same base class

Tags: c#, list, oop

In the below example I would like to be able to put instances of StandardCar or RaceCar into the CarCollection list, then cast them to their correct data types as I loop through the CarCollection List.

I understand this is not possible in C#. But I can't find a way around that doesn't involve one class that has all attributes in a single class. Since NumberOfRaces only applies to RaceCars does it seem messy having it that way?

I'll know if I'm working with Standard Cars or Race Cars when I loop through the collection. But currently, with the code below, if I put a StandardCar into the list, then loop through that list and cast it to a StandardCar I will get a cast exception.

Note my actual final class is a lot more complicated than the below.

```
class Car
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

class RaceCar : Car
{
    public int NumberOfRaces {get; set;}
}

class StandardCar: Car
{
    public bool ChildrenInCar {get; set;}
}    

class CarCollection
{
   List<Car> Collection {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Uhm, sure you can place instances of `StandardCar` and `RaceCar` into the `CarCollection.Collection` property. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: I don't think my question was clear. I've edited to help. I can put them in that List. But I cannot loop through the list and cast them to SandardCar or RaceCar

Comment: Sure you can cast them *back* to `StandardCar` or `RaceCar`, *if they're of that type*. Note that if you place a single `StandardCar` into the list, you can't *cast* that to a `RaceCar`. The question is not clear yet.

Comment: @james You shouldn't want to.  You should leverage polymorphism such that when using the list you don't *need* anything beyond what the base `Car` type exposes.

Comment: If you really have the problem you say you do, that you place an object of type `StandardCar` into the list, then loop through the list, casting it back to `StandardCar`, and it throws an exception, please post a short but complete program that demonstrates, because that *should work just fine*.

Comment: hmm I think my problem maybe further up the line and causing all my "StandardCars" / "RaceCars" to be created as just "Cars". Hence the cast not working. But from what people have said I'm thinking I need to change my approach anyway.

Answer (score 5):

It is perfectly possible, you can add to the list as normal, but to cast back will need to test the types of the car that is returned:

```
// Create the cars
RaceCar rcar = new RaceCar();
StandardCar scar = new StandardCar();

// Add to the collection
CarCollection col = new CarCollection();
col.Add(rcar);
col.Add(scar);

// Iterate
foreach(Car car in col.Collection)
{
    if(car is RaceCar)
    {
        RaceCar racecar = (RaceCar)car;
    }
    else if(car is StandardCar)
    {
        StandardCar standCar = (StandardCar)car;
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

You could also do:

```
car as RaceCar
```

and make sure the returned value is not null.

Note: code is not tested, but should work.

Comment: Having code that does checks like this is code smell, and is a sign that there is a problem with the program's design.

Comment: @Servy While I agree, it is the best way to do what OP asked for without requiring separate collections for each car type.

Comment: We don't know enough about what the OP is actually doing to say what a proper solution is.  Perhaps it'd be separate collections, perhaps leveraging polymorphism, perhaps he doesn't even know what he wants yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a cast works:

```
List<Car> Collection;

..

foreach (Car car in Collection)
{
    RaceCar raceCar = car as RaceCar;
    if (raceCar != null)
    {
       raceCar.NumberOfRaces++;
    }
}
```

Really though this is bad. It's better if possible to not "care" what the specific derived type is. Eg:

```
foreach (Car car in Collection)
{
    car.Update();
}
```

Then RaceCar would have its own implementation of Update() that does stuff with NumberOfRaces. Additionally you might then not require the NumberOfRaces property to have a setter, maybe you don't even need it public.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add `StandardCar` to `List<Car>` collection. What you can't do is easily access derived class specific properties when iteration the collection.

```
var collection = new CarCollection();
collection.Collection= new List<Car>();

collection.Collection.Add(new RaceCar());
collection.Collection.Add(new StandardCar());

foreach (var car in collection.Collection)
    Console.WriteLine(car.Name);
```

Works just fine. What you can't do is:

```
foreach (var car in collection.Collection)
    Console.WriteLine(car.ChildrenInCar);
```

because `ChildrenInCar` exists only in `StandardCar`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities to deal with this problem. Whenever possible you should try to avoid the need for casting. For instance if you want to display the different cars differently, override the `ToString` method. You could also add methods that respond in different ways to different situations. Declare these methods as abstract in the base class (and delcare the base class as abstract as well).

```
abstract class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract void RespondToCollision();
    public abstract void RespondToLoopPerformed();
}

class RaceCar : Car
{
    public int NumberOfRaces {get; set;}

    public override void RespondToCollision()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public override void RespondToLoopPerformed()
    {
        NumberOfRaces++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name = {0}, # of races = {1}", Name, NumberOfRaces);
    }
}

class StandardCar: Car
{
    public bool ChildrenInCar {get; set;}

    public override void RespondToCollision()
    {
        if (ChildrenInCar > 0) {
            ChildrenInCar--;
        }
    }

    public override void RespondToLoopPerformed()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name = {0}, children in car = {1}", 
                             Name, ChildrenInCar);
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to test for the actual type:

```
if (car is RaceCar) {
    ((RaceCar)car).NumberOfRaces++;
} else if (car is StandardCar) {
    ((StandardCar)car).ChildrenInCar = 0;
}
```

Yet another possibility is to filter the car types and process them separately:

```
var raceCars = cars.OfType<RaceCar>();
foreach (raceCar in raceCars) {
   raceCar.NumberOfRaces++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative design is to use interfaces to specify different logical boundaries with the various car objects.

```
interface ICar ...
interface IRacingCar : ICar
interface IFlyingCar : ICar
interface IFamilyCar : ICar
```

Then in your loop you operate on the various cars based on their logical abilities.

```
void ProcessCars()
{
    foreach( var car in cars )
    {
         if(car is IRacingCar) ...
         if(car is IFlyingCar) ...
         if(car is IFamilyCar) ...
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can have many more types of classes without having to have an if statement for every class. Also, your if statement only needs to deal with a single concern at a time.

```
class RaceCar: IRacingCar ...
class FlyingRaceCar: IRaceCar, IFlyingCar ...
class FlyingFamilyCar: IFlyingCar, IFamilyCar ...
```

The loop does not care that a single car can implement multiple interfaces. It only needs to handle a single concern at one time.

For example, any IFlyingCar can deal with gravity and air traffic control without it mattering whether it has children passengers or how many races it has completed.

This is the advantage of interfaces. They allow your consumer of the interface to be concerned with only that quality of the object.

Answer (score -2):

Create an interface:

```
public interface ICar{
//Place all common property / method definitions here
}
```

Make Car implement that interface:

```
public class Car : ICar
{
//implementation
}
```

Then change your CarCollection:

```
public class CarCollection
{
List<ICar> Collection{get; set;}
}
```

Now you should be able to add anything that has a base of Car to that list. When enumerating your collection, all ICars will have those properties / methods defined in the interface accessible to you, without having to casting and type checking.

Comment: You beat me to it, but this is the best way to achieve what OP is looking for.

Comment: Why is this the best way? What does he achieve through this that he doesn't with his existing code? He can place any object into his existing `List<Car>` collection, as long as that object is of a type that is `Car`, or one that inherits from it. There's no need for interfaces here.

Comment: Does not change anything actually. Without interface you have access to properties/methods declared in `Car` class already.

Comment: unnecessary interface

Comment: The interface specification would allow him to specify common properties / methods that ALL of the derived classes have, thus simplifying things when enumerating that collection.

Comment: And he could do that already, by placing all the common properties or methods in the base class.

Comment: Forgive me for preferring to do interface-based programming that lends itself to testability.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon but testability is not an issue for OP. So it does not answer the question.

Comment: The problem here is that **there's nothing wrong with his existing code**. He can do everything he says he wants to do. Adding interfaces won't change that. Sure, using interfaces might give you the opportunity to substitute production objects with mocks or stubs, but that's orthogonal to his question.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon You can test the `Car` class, and each sub-type, just as effectively as you could test an interface with several implementations.

Comment: I'll now bow out of this coding holy war.